# Advanced debugging advice in WPF GarbageCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, finalizer, memory-profiling

**Situation**

We are running a large WPF application which does not release memory for quite some time. It is not a real memory leak, as the memory will be released eventually. I know that normally, this would not be considered to be a problem. Unfortunately it becomes a performance issue in conjunction with the WPF commanding infrastructure. See below for a more detailed description.

**Findings**

We have automated tests, that perform typical use cases. Some cases are working fine and are releasing the memory in time. Others are hogging the memory until the client is minimized, a new Window is opened or some other conditions occur that triggers a Gen2 collection.

•   With ANTS we see, that the objects do not have a GC Root, but a lot of references to other objects that require finalization.

•   WinDbg does not show any objects to be ready for finalization.

•   Running several `GC.Collect()`, `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` completely frees the memory.

•   We know which UI action causes the high memory condition, but we could not identify any suspicious code.

**Question**

We would appreciate any advice on debugging such a problem.

---

**WPF CommandManager Background**

The WPF CommandManager holds private collection of WeakReferences (`_requerySuggestedHandlers`) for raising the `CanExecuteChanged` Event. Handling `CanExecuteChanged` is quite costly (especially finding the EventRoute for `CanExecute`, which apparently is a `RoutedEvent`). Anytime the CommandManager feels like requerying if commands can be executed, it iterates through this collection and calls the `CanExecuteChanged` event on the respective command sources.

The WeakReferences are not removed from that collection as long as there is a GC handle for the referenced object. While the object has not been collected, the CommandHelper keeps processing `CanExecute` events for these elements (ButtonBase or MenuItems). In case there is a lot of garbage (as in our case),  this can result in an extremely large number of calls the CanExecute event handlers, which causes the application to be really laggy.

Comment: Which WPF version are you using? 3.x was known to have some [internal leaks](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/06/WPF-Memory-Leaks).

Comment: We are running 4.0, but the article mentions, that bug KB981107 is still in WPF 4.0 without a hotfix. I'll have a look into that. 

Meanwhile we could isolate the problem in and reproduce it in a sample app. There seems to be something wrong with our DevExpress components.
Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue with one of my applications. On every opening of a window I call:

```
GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
```

This will force GC to clean the memory immediately without waiting. You can read more about this method here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx

About the problem with the calls to CanExecute, I try to avoid them because of the same performance problems. Instead, I use properties in my view model and bind the **IsEnabled** property of the visual elements from XAML to the properties from the view model. In this way, the overall performance is improved and the CanExecute calls are gone.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try CLRProfiler, here's the [downloading link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273). It shows the event handlers allocated, disposed and survived. I am sure you can trace to the root cause by using this tool.
The book Advanced .NET Debugging lists some good tools for debugging, you can read it for some help.